# CSS, JS and Images Links missing when using HTTPS

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

I have a serious problem with the links when using https. My knowledge with using **https** is poor. Although following are the processes that i've done so far.

**Scenario:**

1. I have a site that uses HTTPS. ( Certified )
2. I need only one **CheckOut** page to load in **https** where the checkout page is related to sub-domain. **ex. member.mydomain.com**
3. Site is in **WordPress**
4. Not using WooCommerce !!

**Results:**

1. Using **htaccess** i managed to redirect that certain page ie. **Checkout** page in **https** and it works.
   **ex. https://member.mydomain.com/checkout**

**However, The Problem:**

2. The problem is that all links are dead links in the checkout page due to which it messes up the whole site. The CSS, JS files all are being loaded in **https**.

**What i have tried so far !!**

1. I tried updating the general settings url to https. So, it works but the same issue to all pages. All the links are broken.
2. Followed the instructions on this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75921/ssl-breaks-wordpress-css
3. Also, in this https://managewp.com/wordpress-ssl-settings-and-how-to-resolve-mixed-content-warnings

But the above did not seem to do the trick. I still have the broken links. What am i missing here? Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide more informations? Your `.htaccess` file and a css or js link that does not work and the actual link that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution finally.. Tried modifying the htaccess file again.

Following is what i added in my htaccess in order to fix the problem. It might be useful to someone in the future.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#-------------------SUB.DOMAIN.COM---------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/members%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule . %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/members%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . subdirectory/index.php [L]
#-----------------SUB.DOMAIN.COM---------------------

</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This solved the subdomain issue and the 500 error requests as well as the broken links problem.